# How to increase the space for dfs on HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We have 4 datanode HDFS cluster ...there is large amount of space avialable on each data node of about 98gb ...but when i look at the datanode information ..
it's only using about 10gb ...

[image: DataNode Information]

How can we make it use all the 98gb and not run out of space as indicated in image

this is the hdfs-site.xml on name node

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
        <value>2368709120</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.available-space-volume-choosing-policy.balanced-space-preference-fraction</name>
        <value>1.0</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

this is the hdfs-site.xml under data node

```
<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.du.reserved</name>
        <value>2368709120</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.fsdataset.volume.choosing.policy</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.available-space-volume-choosing-policy.balanced-space-preference-fraction</name>
        <value>1.0</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

**the 98gb is under /test**

[image]

Please let us know if we missed anything in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *dfs.datanode.data.dir* in the hdfs-site.xml. This property would control all the directories which can be used to store DFS blocks.

[Documentation Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

So on you machines execute "df -h" that should list all the mount points which make up the 98 GB. Then in each of the mount points decide which directory can be used to store HDFS block data and add those under hdfs-site.xml comma separated for dfs.datanode.data.dir. Then retstart namenode and all data node services.

And from your edited post :

```
   <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
```

It should not be **file://**. It should look like :

```
   <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/test/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
```

Same for other properties.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer Venkat ...i have added the hdfs-site.xml for both name node and data node ..please let us know if anything needs to be changed in the configuration

Comment: Thanks for the update Venkat ..as i mentioned in the question the 98gb is mounted under "/test" which i have l already included in the hdfs-site.xml

Comment: I noticed that. So I think the file:// should not be there. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: i tried it Venkat removing file:// and restarting all services ... but still its showing capacity at the same 14gb ...and not 93gb